# Change Google spreadsheet cell contents based on the contents of other cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a 'new' Google spreadsheet, I want to monitor the contents of particular cells to have a "status" cell automatically show the progress of an order.

Can anyone help me with a script that would automatically alter the contents of cell K8:K, depending upon the contents of cells L8:L, R8:R, Y8:Y, AA8:AA and AB8:AB?

Please forgive the syntax, I've never learned a script language...
The logic would go something like this:

```
If L<>0 then K="Awaiting order"
If R<>0 or Q<>0 then K="In progress"
If AA<>0 and Y=0 then K="Sent for invoicing (docs incomplete)"
If AA<>0 and Y<>0 then K="Sent for invoicing (docs complete)"
If AB<>0 and Y<>0 then K="Closed (complete)"
```

I'm using "<>0" to indicate that something has been entered into the cell and "=0" to indicate that the cell is empty.
If multiple arguments were true, then the later one in the sequence should take precedence.

Back when I knew how to program, you could use lots of IF/ELSE statements to achieve the desired priorities, but I really have no clue where to start these days, except Google, which, when looking for info about how to achieve complex Google Spreadsheet tasks, usually leads me to Stack Overflow!

Any help will be gratefully received!

Comment: So, the spreadsheet that is doing the monitoring is not the same spreadsheet with the data?

Comment: It is just one spreadsheet.  When I said "new", I did mean the one with the green tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly a formula rather than a script but please try in K8 and copied down to suit:

```
=if(and(AB8<>"",Y8<>""),"Closed (complete)",if(and(AA8<>"",Y8=""),"Sent for invoicing (docs complete)",if(and(AA8<>"",Y8<>""),"Sent for invoicing (docs incomplete)",if(R8<>"","In progress",if(L8<>"","Awaiting order","")))))
```

Comment: How do I make it so that if either Q8 or R8 <>0, then "In progress"?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a combination of nested [if](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) functions and the [isBlank](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290) function in the formulae in column K.

So to model just the first part of what you're trying to do, the formula in K8 might be something like:

```
if( not(isBlank(L8)), "Awaiting Order", if( not(isBlank(R8)), "In Progress", "Other conditions go here" ) )
```

You indicated in the comments you want to do an [or](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306) function as well. The syntax for just that part might be

```
or( isBlank(Q9), isBlank(R9) )
```

Comment: Thanks Prisoner, that's really helpful.  It's almost working now... I'm using plain isBlank though rather than NOT.  Can you tell me how to include a logical OR operator?  I'm trying this (isBlank(Q9))*(isBlank(R9)) but it seems to just ignore the Q9 part?

Comment: answer update to include info about the "or" operator.